# How to present sql queries using diagram?

Tags: sql, oracle, uml, data-modeling, diagram

I will do a presentation where I will present some complex sql queries. The audience has no idea about my project, so I cannot just explain by showing the query. I need a tool (diagram?) that allows me to explain my query. Using class diagran or ER diagram is not enough because I want to represent every thing in my query like joins, loops, cursors...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your question is not about programming, and therefore it does not belong on Stack Overflow. It's a legitimate question, no doubt - you are just asking it in the wrong place. If the question gets closed again and you ask it a third time, I will flag it as a violation.

Comment: I think we can talk about uml and diagrams here. It is not only reserved for programming. Database is not programming and we can talk about it

Comment: The other topic doesn't answer my question

Comment: "Database is not programming" is wrong. We access the database through queries (primarily SQL), and we manipulate the data with various programming languages, including ones developed specifically for the database, such as PL/SQL (in addition to general purpose languages like Java and C#). This site is for programming questions, and the `sql` and `oracle` (etc.) tags are for programming in SQL, while the `plsql` tag is for PL/SQL programming questions. You tagged your post with `uml`, for example - but you don't have a specific UML question, do you?

Comment: query can be presented as execution plan, drive tables and sequence of access tables/views, and how they are joined, is that what you look for?

Comment: @scottyu Yes how can present all of that clearly, so people can understand my work?

Comment: because stackoverflow is mostly words based, I try to explained as word of sql programer/dba,

Comment: in oracle sqlplus you can set autotrace on, you can generate explain plan, that will tell you driving tables access path(like fiter, or join keys)